# Waiting for promise to resolve before continuing

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I want to wait for my axios function to continue executing so I can get the url from the response before executing my code further. How can I wait for the promise to resolve?

```
 for (i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i++) {

                if(responseArray[i].id === "text"){

                    var id = responseArray[i].firstChild.firstChild.id

                responses.push({
                    type : 'text',
                    data : $("#" + id).val()
                })

                }
                else if(responseArray[i].id === "image"){
                     var fileID = responseArray[i].firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.lastChild.id
                    console.log(fileID)
                    var file = $('#'+fileID)[0].files[0]
                    var formData = new FormData()
                    formData.append('file',file)
                    formData.append('upload_preset',preset)
                    console.log(formData)
                    axios({
                        url: uploadURL,
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        },
                        data:formData,

                    }).then(function(res) {

                        responses.push({
                            type : 'image',
                            data : res.data.url
                        })
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    })

                }


            }

            data = {}
            data.responses = responses
             console.log(data.responses)
```

I wanna store the responses in my data object. But it doesnt wait for axios to stop executing.

Comment: Put your console.log in the `then`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Would you mind providing an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your code is quite hard to reason about as is. Maybe formatting could help too?

Comment: The `then` isn't needed with `await`, the `res` will return as a value:

`let res = await axios({...})`

Comment: @James I'm sorry but what I wanna do is store all the responses from the if statements and store it in the data object. How can I make sure that axios is finish executing before I store all the responses.

Comment: Where are you defining `async`?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn sorry that await was unnecessary and I removed it